# need correct syntax for command to launch local jupyter notebook server and open .ipynb file in OneDrive folder location

Tags: jupyter-notebook, onedrive, launching-application

I have a Jupyter .ipynb NB file in a OneDrive folder location

I want to open the .ipynb NB in my local jupyter notebook server and run it without copying the file down from the OneDrive location.

The normal way to do this with a file system is :

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="c:\users\myaccount\nb_folders"
```

and it will launch the jupyter server from that folders location.

I tried to emulate this when I open a .ipynb file in a OneDrive folder that I can only access through a browser, since I cannot run the local OneDrive client (or dropbox client) on my corporate computer due to security reasons.

Instead of a file path, I want to include a OneDrive URL that points to the .ipynb file.

I typed in the following command after the command prompt >>

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir='https://onedrive.live.com/?id=8451683B31A67FC5%2111876&cid=845xxxxxx'
```

I get the following error that I don't know how to interpret:

[C 02:12:28.460 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 02:12:28.460 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: '"C:\Users\myaccount\'https:\onedrive.live.com\?id=8451683B31A67F
C5%xxxxxx"'
'cid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(base) C:\Users\myaccount>>

#

The full message from the Anaconda console is:

jupyter: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required
'cid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(base) C:\Users\myaccount>> jupyter notebook --notebook-dir='https://onedrive.live.com/?id=8451683B31A67FC5%2111876&cid=845
1683B31A67FC5'

[C 02:12:28.460 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 02:12:28.460 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: '"C:\Users\myaccount\'https:\onedrive.live.com\?id=8451683B31A67F
C5%xxxxxx"'
'cid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Why do not you save your OneDrive `.ipynb `file in a temp directory and then try opening the file from that tmp location?

Comment: I could do that if I had permissions to install OneDrive locally in Windows, but I do NOT have permissions on this corporate computer.   Hence, I don't have any local machine OneDrive folders, only online Cloud folders.